# При установки Android Studio возникла ошибка с HAXM

Tags: android-studio

Я так понимаю, ошибка установки возникла из-за того, что у меня процессор AMD. Прав ли я? Если да, это нужно проигнорировать?

Вот вывод с ошибкой:

```
Running Intel® HAXM installer
Failed to install Intel HAXM. For details, please check the installation log: "C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_log.txt"
HAXM installation failed. To install HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://software.intel.com/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows
Installer log is located at C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_log.txt
Installer log contents:
=== Logging started: 31.12.2018  14:59:30 ===
This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. 
Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.

=== Logging stopped: 31.12.2018  14:59:30 ===
```

Comment: да, это для процесоров intel - драйвер их виртуализации (используется для эмулятора Android). насчет процессоров amd вот [последние новости](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html?m=1). если ваша девелоперская машина не соответствует этим требованиям, то о официальном эмуляторе лучше забыть, так как его работа будет невыносимо медленной. тогда есть вариант использовать geny motion или реальное устройство