# Проблемы при запуске проекта в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Создал простой проект(вернее его IDE сгенерировала) и запустил.

В итоге IDE вывела ошибку:

```
22:24   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

22:24   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

22:24   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

22:24   Gradle build finished in 1 s 595 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Данная ошибка у меня тоже встречалась, долго ковырялся и в итоге включил виртуализацию в системе и все заработало. Эта ошибка указывает вам на необходимость включить виртуализацию, потому что она необходима для корректной работы эмулятора. Вот какой [источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration) я использовал для решения своей проблемы, может и вам поможет. Удачи, у вас все получится :)

Comment: В том посте, кажется, про обсуждение про проблемы на проце Intel, у меня же AMD. Вот был у меня вопрос при установке Android Studio https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927293/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-android-studio-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-haxm . Возможно, это как раз последствия.

Comment: Вообщем, мне получилось запустить виртуальную машину только с помощью genymotion. Есть ли другие пути решения?

Comment: @SonicMyst genymotion быстрее стандартного эмулятора в Android Studio, так что пользуйтесь и работает он с помощью virtualbox

Comment: страндартный эмулятор как и студия имеет кучу плюсов и минусов, лично я какое-то время попользовавшись встроенным эмулятором увидел что особых плюсов нет, только озу жрет и может предложить не намного больше чем genymotion, так что если нет особой разницы на чем тестировать то советую остаться на на genymotiona в чем полностью согласен с @danilshik.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko кстати хотел спросить, почему в 3 версии Android Studio вырезали функционал, который позволял просматривать как выглядит макет сразу на всех устройствах (разные размеры экрана)

Comment: @danilshik, сложно предположить почему разработчики так решили сделать, а я не разрабатывал ас )) но могу допустить что это связанно с тем что они работали над усовершенствованием превью макета в xml и что-то полетело как-всегда. Будем надеяться что пофиксят в будущих апдейтах :)

Comment: @danilshik может быть не хуже стандартного эмулятора, но он платный или я не прав?

Comment: он бесплатный)))

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko https://www.genymotion.com/pricing-desktop/ - что же это тогда?

Comment: https://www.comss.ru/download/page.php?id=2875 - я отсюда брал))) все бесплатно

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko короче он не бесплатен походу, по крайней мере на официальном сайте не нашел.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88301/discussion-between-sonic-myst-and-andrew-goroshko).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый